# Accessing Events And Members In The Master Page

Tags: asp.net

I have an event in the Master page that I want to access in the pages that use that master page but it doesn't seem to be working.

In the Master

```
public delegate void NotifyRequest(object sender, EventArgs e);
public class MyMaster
{
   public event NotifyRequest NewRequest;
   protected void uiBtnNewTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   { 
      if(NewRequest!= null)
         NewRequest(this, e)
   }
}
```

Inherited Page

```
MyMaster mm = new MyyMaster();
mm.NewRequest += new NotifyRequest(mm_NotifyRequest);
void mm_NotifyRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Wow";
    this.Label1.Visible = true;
}
```

My problem is the event is always null. Any ideas?

Comment: In your code sample above, you are registering to "NewRequest", but checking if "NotifyRequest" is null.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes it was a typo, I have fixed it now thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *probably* need to use the following syntax to access your event in the Master Page

```
((MyMaster)Master).NewRequest += new NotifyRequest(mm_NotifyRequest);
```

If you wish to access members of a master page you need to use the page **Master** attribute  and cast it to your master page.

Alternately

If you wish do not wish to use a cast you can use the @MasterType directive to create a strong reference to your master page, in this case MyMaster. So you would be able to access your event like so: **Master.NewRequest**.

[More Reading about Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h(VS.85).aspx)